# Spring - sending form gives back null object using Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

When I send some data using form it sends null object to controller and I don't know why. I think I have done everything like it was in tutorial but my program does not work properly. Please help :(
I could bet that it is some obvious mistake in code that I don't see because of lack of experience.

**Model** (I have decided to not use constructor because I don't know how to use it in Spring yet)

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Product {
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public BigDecimal price;

    public Product(String name, String description, BigDecimal price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Product() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.sklepp.service.Product;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class ProductDao {

    private List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(
            new Product("Tea", "green", new BigDecimal("25.00")),
            new Product("Coffee", "black", new BigDecimal("30.00")));
           

    public List<Product> all() {
        return products;
    }

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        this.products.add(product);
    }

    public Product byName(String name) {
        for (Product product : products) {
            if (name.equals(product.getName())) {
                return product;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**My controller**

```
import com.example.sklepp.dao.ProductDao;
import com.example.sklepp.service.Product;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("admin")
public class AdminController {

    private final ProductDao productDao;

    public AdminController(ProductDao productDao) {
        this.productDao = productDao;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String admin(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("newProduct", new Product());
        return "admin/admin";
    }


    @PostMapping("/add-product")
    public String addProduct(@ModelAttribute Product product) {
        System.out.println(product.getName());
        return "redirect:/sklep";
    }
}
```

**My template**

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin service</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>ADMIN</h1>

<p>+++++++++++++++++++++</p>

<form th:action="@{/admin/add-product}" th:object="${newProduct}" method="post">
    <p>Adding new product: </p>
    <p>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"></p>
    <p>Price: <input type="text" th:field="*{price}"></p>
    <p>Description: <input type="text" th:field="*{description}"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add product"></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding setters to your model class? Many frameworks rely on (Standard) getters and setters and often fail silently when those are not available.

Comment: May be you should use some annotation in your model class, something like @Model. Btw, why your attributes have public visibility?